PHPMailer with Google SMTP does not throw exception when sends mail to not existing address
I recently configured PHPMailer with google's SMTP. The setup works well when it is about sending mails to existing addresses, however the problem begins when I send email to a not existing mail.
Let's say I send a mail to sample@mail.com. My server sends it without errors, but later I get an email like this:
FROM: mailer-daemon@googlemail.com

Delivery Status Notification (Failure)

Address not found

The response from the remote server was:
550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable For explanation visit https://postmaster.mail.com/en/case?c=r1601&i=ip&v=209.85.218.44&r=0MMkTR-1tRvZc35wN-008XeL

Basically I get a wrong error response, because I want to handle it in my server.
My code for sending looks like this:
        $this->mail = new PHPMailer(true); // exceptions enabled
        $this->mail->isSMTP();
        $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $this->mail->Host = env('mail.host'); // smtp.gmail.com
        $this->mail->Port = env('mail.port'); // 587
        $this->mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $this->mail->Username = env('mail.user');
        $this->mail->Password = env('mail.pass');
        $this->mail->setFrom(env('mail.from'), env('mail.from.username'));
 
       $this->mail->addAddress($recipient);
       $this->mail->isHTML(true);
       $this->mail->Subject = $subject;
       $this->mail->Body = $body;
       if(!$this->mail->send()) {
        throw new MailException($this->mail->ErrorInfo); // custom exception that I handle later
       }

I am thinking about changing my mail.user and mail.pass to a google account's credentials, because right now I am using one from my company. Hopefully that will solve it.
Up until that, I appreciate any help.

That's how SMTP servers work. The email is added to a queue and processed asynchronously.

…and increasingly so, because it also prevents spammers from scanning addresses

I’m voting to close this question because it isn’t really a bug, but a misunderstanding of how email works

Don't think of send() as the act of actually sending the message, think of it as putThisMessageInTheOutgoingBin(). At some undefined point in the future, it may or may not be delivered. If you want to know about those that have eventually failed, you will need to perform bounce detection, which is made much simpler if you use an API service like MailGun or SES.
